# Space images in an array out evenly, taking into account different image widths

Tags: arrays, image, lua, spacing

```
local xOffset = 0

for i = 1, levelPacks[prevCurrentLevelPack][prevCurrentLevel].ammount do

    if i == 1 then --setup first one

        shapesPrevArray[i].x = 30
        shapesPrevArray[i].y = 41
        shapesPrevArray[i].isVisible = true

    end

    if i > 1 then --setup the rest

        --width of previous one plus the x value of the previous one to make them next to eachother.
        xOffset = shapesPrevArray[i - 1].width + shapesPrevArray[i - 1].x
        print("offset: " .. xOffset)
        shapesPrevArray[i].x = xOffset    
        shapesPrevArray[i].y = 41
        shapesPrevArray[i].isVisible = true
        xOffset = 0

    end

    i = i + 1

end


i:2 width:60 x value:30 xoffset:90
i:3 width:40 x value:90 xoffset:130
i:4 width:50 x value:130 xoffset:180
i:5 width:70 x value:180 xoffset:250
```

Can anyone help me out please? I can't work out why this bit isn't spacing them out.

xOffset = shapesPrevArray[i - 1].width + shapesPrevArray[i - 1].x

If someone could explain why it isn't and point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `i = i + 1`

> A numeric for has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> for var=exp1,exp2,exp3 do
>   something
> end
> ```
>
> That loop will execute something for each value of var from exp1 to
>   exp2, using exp3 as the step to increment var. This third expression
>   is optional; when absent, Lua assumes one as the step value.

http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html

Comment: Thanks removed it, any idea why the shapes aren't spacing correctly?

Comment: can you print i, shapesPrevArray[i - 1].width, shapesPrevArray[i - 1].x with xOffset and leave them in your question?

Comment: I don't see any problem with xoffset as it is growing properly. Your problem might not be in the code here.

Comment: all of my code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/itiEzRJK I can show you how my images are printing if you like its strange. What it looks like onscreen can be found here: [IMG]http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/6472916/img/6472916.png[/IMG]

Comment: You need to post a new question with the corrected loop code as my answer won't be valid if you change your question like this.

Comment: Ok, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302906/images-in-an-array-not-spacing-correctly Thanks again.