# Images in an array, not spacing correctly

Tags: arrays, image, lua, spacing, lua-table

The shapes are at the top of the image.

http://picturepush.com/public/6472916

The code looks like this:

```
    local xOffset = 0

    for i = 1, levelPacks[prevCurrentLevelPack][prevCurrentLevel].ammount do

        if i == 1 then --setup first one

            shapesPrevArray[i].x = 30
            shapesPrevArray[i].y = 41
            shapesPrevArray[i].isVisible = true

        end

        if i > 1 then --setup the rest

            --width of previous one plus the x value of the previous one to make them next to eachother.
            xOffset = shapesPrevArray[i - 1].width + shapesPrevArray[i - 1].x
            print("i:" .. i .. " width:" .. shapesPrevArray[i - 1].width .. " x value:" .. shapesPrevArray[i - 1].x .." xoffset:" .. xOffset)
            shapesPrevArray[i].x = xOffset    
            shapesPrevArray[i].y = 41
            shapesPrevArray[i].isVisible = true
            xOffset = 0

        end

    end
```

I'm trying to space all of the images in the array out with the same space between each image. Images in the array have different width. The .x value is at the top left corner of the shapes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this code would put the shapes right next to each other, without space between them. This is not the case in the screenshot. Is each shape just the white part, or does it also include some black?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, the shapes are not image files they are rectangles which are defined by setting the width and height values. which I then scale down half way. So there shouldn't be any black!

Comment: Either that, or .width didn't get initialized properly...

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment, the `width` of each shape is actually twice what it will be drawn as. So what you have to do is add up all the widths and divide the sum by 2; this gives you the total width needed by the shapes. Subtract this from the total width on the screen you want to take up; this gives you the amount of space available. Then divide that by the number of shapes, minus one; this gives you the amount of space to add to the right of each shape (approximately, since it probably won't divide exactly; just round down). So each shape's offset is the offset of the previous shape, plus half its width, plus the value we just calculated. I don't know Lua so I'll leave the coding to you.

Comment: Thanks for this it works perfectly, although when a smaller image is next to a larger image it kind of messes the spacing up a little. http://picturepush.com/public/6472963 is there anyway to get round that? Thanks again, Lewis.

Comment: @Lewis Elliott: This is actually quite a bit off; I measure these numbers of pixels: 20 (gap 41) 25 (gap 44) 35 (gap 29) 15. I suggest you add the new code to the question (while keeping the old code) so it can be reviewed.

Comment: I've uploaded what you told me in Lua, and made it simpler so people can see where the shapes are coming from. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309452/spacing-images-in-an-array-out-accurately-with-even-spaces-between-each-image